# Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed

Tags: php, error-handling

I'm getting the error below...

Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in \wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions.php on line 1335

at...

```
function my_get_tags_sitemap(){
    if ( !function_exists('wp_tag_cloud') || get_option('cb2_noposttags')) return;
    $unlinkTags = get_option('cb2_unlinkTags'); 
    echo '<div class="tags"><h2>Tags</h2>';
    if($unlinkTags)
    {
        $tags = get_tags();
        foreach ($tags as $tag){
            $ret[]= $tag->name;
        }
        //ERROR OCCURS HERE
        echo implode(', ', $ret);
    }
    else
    {
        wp_tag_cloud('separator=, &smallest=11&largest=11');
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Any ideas how to intercept the error. The site has exactly one tag.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You are getting the error because `$ret` is not an array.

To get rid of the error, at the start of your function, define it with this line: `$ret = array();`

It appears that the get_tags() call is returning nothing, so the foreach is not run, which means that $ret isn't defined.

Answer (score 38):

You can try

```
echo implode(', ', (array)$ret);
```

Answer (score 2):

It happens when `$ret` hasn't been defined. The solution is simple. Right above `$tags = get_tags();`, add the following line:

```
$ret = array();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function my_get_tags_sitemap(){
    if ( !function_exists('wp_tag_cloud') || get_option('cb2_noposttags')) return;
    $unlinkTags = get_option('cb2_unlinkTags'); 
    echo '<div class="tags"><h2>Tags</h2>';
    $ret = []; // here you need to add array which you call inside implode function
    if($unlinkTags)
    {
        $tags = get_tags();
        foreach ($tags as $tag){
            $ret[]= $tag->name;
        }
        //ERROR OCCURS HERE
        echo implode(', ', $ret);
    }
    else
    {
        wp_tag_cloud('separator=, &smallest=11&largest=11');
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to say why this answer is better than the other 4 already posted?

Comment: Actually I don't argue with you but here I'm trying to mention where to add the array().