# Waring : implode()[function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed

Tags: php

> Waring : implode()[function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed

```
if($_REQUEST['noofRooms']>0){
    for($i=0;$i<$_REQUEST['noofRooms'];$i++){
        $r_PackDetails =$_SESSION['PackDetails'][$i];
        $adults =$r_PackDetails['adults'];
        $childs =$r_PackDetails['childs'];
        $childAge_arr =$r_PackDetails['childAge'];
        $xmldata.='<Room><numberOfAdults>'.$adults.'</numberOfAdults>';
        if($childs>0){
            $childAge =implode(",",$childAge_arr);//ERROR occurs in this LINE
            $xmldata.='<numberOfChildren>'.$childs.'</numberOfChildren>';
            $xmldata.='<childAges>'.$childAge.'</childAges>';
        }
```

Comment: wow nice question

Comment: befor `if` check `print($childs);print($childAge_arr);` and show us the value of those

Comment: ok let me try and tel u

Comment: yes, its getting the value. but error remains the same

Comment: I don't get the value of print($childs);

Comment: Inspect whether '$r_PackDetails['childAge']'is an array, like if is_array($r_PackDetails['childAge']) {} . The is going to be a an issue. But your have did not provide your input data, so it's hard to help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: implode() \[function.implode\]: Invalid arguments passed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280180/warning-implode-function-implode-invalid-arguments-passed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you check that variable is array or not. Then you pass it into implode function. If that variable is not an array then it will throw **Invalid arguments passed**. So check,

```
if(!empty($childAge_arr)) {
    $childAge =implode(",",$childAge_arr);
}
```

Comment: No actually all the variables are passing in the array. where as I have printed the value and checked it. but doesn't know why that error remains the same.